# Changing Value of a Register using PIN binary instrumentation tool

Tags: intel-pin

I am trying to make some changes to the value of a register using PIN_SetContextReg. First I get the value of REG_INST_PTR using PIN_GetContextReg as old_val, then I wanna make some changes to this value and set it at the same register as new_val. What are possible random values that I can use. Also what other registers besides REG_INST_PTR can I change that will have a significant impact on the program am instrumenting.

Here is the method

```
static  UINT32 old_val;
static  UINT32 new_val;
VOID changeRegisterValue(CONTEXT *ctxt ) {  
    old_val = PIN_GetContextReg(ctxt,   REG_INST_PTR);
    new_val =  ??
    PIN_SetContextReg(ctxt, REG_INST_PTR, new_val);
}
```

The method is called here

```
VOID Instruction(INS ins, VOID *v)
{          
    INS_InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE,      (AFUNPTR)changeRegisterValue,IARG_CONTEXT, IARG_END);

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by changing the instruction pointer (`eip` / `rip`) of your program? Changing any register will have a profound impact on the program, and especially the instruction pointer as it changes the program code flow.

Comment: I am trying to do some register level fault injections by the changing the values of the register and then study the behavior the program thereafter.

Comment: I think you can refer to codes at github for some hints https://github.com/search?q=PIN_SetContextReg&type=Code

Comment: Here is a working example https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/17842/24634